# ASP.Net radio button will not change state

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

In an asp.net form, I have a set of radio buttons, all with the same groupID.  On the same form I have a reset button.  In the code for the reset button I set the radio button I want to be the default to checked, as in rb.Checked = true.  The problem is that the checked state of the radio buttons does not change.  Why not?

ASP.Net:

```
 <asp:Table ID="tblFullText" runat="server" Width="95%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="10pt" CellSpacing="0"
 BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="0" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#c0c0c0">
  <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="LightSteelBlue" Font-Bold="True">
    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3" Font-Bold="true" Text="FULL TEXT SEARCH PARAMETERS"></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="LightSteelBlue" Font-Bold="True">
  <asp:TableCell Width="50%" Text="Search Criteria"></asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell Width="17%" Text="Query Operator"></asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell Width="33%" Text="Query Expression Type"></asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableCell Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Center"><asp:textbox id="tbFullTextSearchCriteria" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:textbox></asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell Width="17%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryOp" ID="rbQueryOpAnd" Text="<b>AND</b>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryOp" ID="rbQueryOpOR" Text="<b>OR</b>" />
  </asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell Width="33%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryExpType" ID="rbQueryExpTypeAll" Text="<b>All Words</b>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryExpType" ID="rbQueryExpTypeAny" Text="<b>Any Word</b>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryExpType" ID="rbQueryExpTypeExact" Text="<b>Exact Phrase</b>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton runat="server" GroupName="QueryExpType" ID="rbQueryExpTypeExpr" Text="<b>Expression</b>" />
  </asp:TableCell>
  </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Code behind:

```
  Protected Sub btnClearFields_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearFields.Click

    rbQueryOpAnd.Checked = True

  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set other `RadioButton`s in the same group to false.

```
Protected Sub btnClearFields_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
   Handles btnClearFields.Click

    rbQueryOpAnd.Checked = True
    rbQueryOpOR.Checked = False

End Sub
```

If you do not want to set other `RadioButton` to false, you need to use `RadioButtonList`.